# Need I query twice in a polymorphic query in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a polymorphic mapping:

base is Person, sub entity is employee and manager etc.

mapping in single table strategy.

I got an ID of Person, but I don't know it's subtype ( employee or manager).

each subtype has it's own field/column.

How can I retrieve data in one hibernate query?

Need I query twice (first get the subtype or discriminal column) then get the detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need several queries.

```
select p from Person p
```

will return all the persons. The result will be a list of persons, containing `Manager` and `Employee` instances.

```
select p from Person p where id = :id
```

will return the person having the given ID. If it happens to be an employee, you'll get back an `Employee` instance. If it happens to be a manager, you'll get back a `Manager` instance.